# How do I avoid injuries working with a table saw?

Tags: tools

What are the most common mistakes newcomers make? Is there a safer alternative to a table saw?

Comment: IIRC, there was some good discussion of this on woodworking.stackexchange.com  (And if not, this question might be better there.)

Comment: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-prevent-dangerous-kickback-on-a-table-saw/82#82 (Though kickback isn't the only thing, it's a biggie.)

Comment: This is going to sound *really* elementary, but of the handful of people I've known who have been injured by table saws got distracted, too focused, or whatever, and simply forgot where the blade was in relation to their hands.

Comment: The safer alternative is a hand saw. Not as fast but much safer. 

Comment: There's a [table saw](http://www.sawstop.com/why-sawstop/the-technology) with a safety device that will stop the blade instantly if it comes into contact with skin -- fast enough to prevent serious injury.

Answer (score 3):

There is, NOW, a big sign in my work area that says *SLOW DOWN*.

I was ripping a piece of MDF for a door panel and I mismeasured - 1/2 inch too narrow. Angry, frustrated, and in a hurry to get back to the project.

Remeasured, remarked, and mounted another panel to cut to size. Pushed the panel along the fence and didn't slow down to make sure the cutoff piece had cleared the blade.

The cutoff touched the blade and came flying back at me, hitting me in the face, hand and arm. Safety glasses saved my face, bad bruise on the arm and a cut along the side of my hand that needed three stitches.

After I got back from the hospital, the cutoff (with a big scar through it where the blade chewed it up) was left right next to  the saw with the legend, SLOW DOWN.

SPEED KILLS!